# Drop an image in a specific region

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have an image gallery and I intend to drag and drop these images into a drop zone.

I tried to use it in two cases (using the mouse to drag the image and using the cdk drag & drop that allows me to move the image to the drops area as well).

Is there a way to get the object (name, id ...) from the image that is dropped in the drop zone? I try to drag the image to the drop zone and when I release it there, I want to know which image was dropped.

Is there a way to achieve this? Can someone help me?

Thank you very much!

[**DEMO - STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckdlsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.TS**

```
     onFileDropped($event) {
        this.prepareFilesList($event);
        console.log("evt", $event )

      }

      fileBrowseHandler(files) {
      this.prepareFilesList(files);
      }

      async prepareFilesList(files: Array<any>) {

      }

   @HostBinding('class.fileover') fileOver: boolean;
    @HostBinding('style.background-color') private background = '#f5fcff'
    @Output() fileDropped = new EventEmitter<any>();

    // Dragover listener
    @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      this.fileOver = true;
      this.background = '#9ecbec';
    }

    // Dragleave listener
    @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      this.background = '#f5fcff'
      this.fileOver = false;
    }

    // Drop listener
    @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      this.background = '#f5fcff'
      this.fileOver = false;
      let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

      this.fileDropped.emit(files);

    }
```

Using the images (cdkDrag) I was unable to get any events in the drop zone that detect the entry of something.

Using normal images, I was able to execute the function

```
 onFileDropped ($ event) {
    this.prepareFilesList ($ event);
    console.log ("evt", $ event)

  }
```

but I didn't get results as the image shows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is create a @input property in directive and assign value to that on mousedown from component

dnd directive

```
 @Input() data;
```

component.html

```
//add [data]="selectedProduct" 

     <div class="card-body">
          <div class="mycontainer" appDnd [data]="selectedProduct" (fileDropped)="onFileDropped(sle)">
              <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; justify-content: center;">
                <span>Drop your items here.</span>   
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

//add (mousedown)="assignSelectedProduct(product)"

    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of data; let  j = index;">
      <li class="mdc-image-list__item" (mousedown)="assignSelectedProduct(product)" >
        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
          <ng-container *ngIf="product.image == null; else productImage">
            <img src="" class="mdc-image-list__image imagenotfound">
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #productImage>
            <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
          </ng-template>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
                    <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting mdc-image-list__supporting">
                        <span class="mdc-image-list__label">{{product.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
selectedProduct; 

assignSelectedProduct(product){
  this.selectedproduct = product;
}
```

dnd directive

```
  // Drop listener
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt) {
  console.log(this.data, 'data');
  }
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !